# How to set unique id in mongodb with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have data like this

```
Mywants:[
    {"title":"lap","rate":$20}
    {"title":"lap","rate":$20}
    {"title":"lap","rate":$20}
]
```

If I save new data into array(mywant) I should save with new unique id so how to save like that using javascript. So it should be look like:

```
Mywants:[
    {"title":"lap","rate":$20,_id:objectId("512640f3243c837c0e0004401}
    {"title":"lap","rate":$20,_id:objectId("512640f3243c837254000001}
    {"title":"lap","rate":$20,_id:objectId("512640f3243c8372540257001}}
]
```

To insert I am using command like

```
collection.update({"userid":1248787885},{$push:{"Mywant":{"title":"car","rate":$100}}});
```

Answer (score 2):

As andyb notes, you have to generate the `ObjectId` for your new element by constructing a new one.  But you don't need a separate library:

```
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
collection.update(
    {"userid":1248787885},
    {$push:{"Mywant":{
        _id: new mongodb.ObjectID(),
        "title":"car",
        "rate":$100
    }}});
```

Of course, `$100` isn't a valid JavaScript type, but I assume you know that.  It's also worth noting that [Mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/) does this adding of `_id` fields to array elements for you, so that's another alternative.

Comment: i have given same as above coding but it is showing error in semicolon.$push:{"Mywant":{
        _id: new mongodb.ObjectID();
        "title":"car",
        "rate":$100}} is this correct syntax or not? i think it is wrong syntax.

Answer (score 1):

To generate mongoDB [`ObjectId`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/object-id/) in JavaScript you can use an existing library or implement the BSON ObjectId specification yourself. [ObjectId.js](https://github.com/justaprogrammer/ObjectId.js) is one such library and getting an Id is as simple as:

```
var objectId = new ObjectId();
```

Comment: if i update new data into array it would not create new object id.so tell me correct answer.

Comment: I have updated my answer with a link to a JavaScript library for generating `ObjectId`s

Answer (score 0):

In javascript there is one method called Math.random() it will create dynamic random number so you can modify this number as dynamic id.